# CKEditor5: enabling source view in read-only mode

Tags: event-handling, ckeditor, readonly, ckeditor5

I'm trying to create a CKEditor that is **read-only but allows source view**.
When I use CKEditor's read-only mode, the source editing plugin gets disabled.

I'm looking for an **easy way** to do this, I don't want to write a custom plugin.

I was thinking of disabling the editor window via HTML property, capturing the click on the sourceEditing button and then disabling the source code textarea.

However, in the CKEditor documentation, I cannot find a simple method to capture the click event on a specific toolbar button.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Tom